# Converting a base 20 number to decimal

Tags: c

I have been asked to convert a number in base 20 to decimal,
where the number in base 20 is entered by the user in reverse order.
For example if the original number is `F1` the input is `1F`.

- I can only use the standard library `<stdio.h>`, loops and conditions.

This is what I have done so far that does not seem to work.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int sum = 0;
    int exp = 1;
    char reverse_char;
    printf("Enter a reversed number in base 20:");
    scanf(" %c", &reverse_char);
    while (reverse_char != '\n') {
        if ((reverse_char >= '0') && (reverse_char < '10') || ((reverse_char >= 'a') && (reverse_char < 'k')) || ((reverse_char >= 'A') && (reverse_char < 'k'))) {
            if ((reverse_char >= '0') && (reverse_char < '10')) {
                reverse_char = reverse_char - '0';
                sum += (reverse_char * exp);
                exp = exp * 20;
            }
            else if ((reverse_char >= 'a') && (reverse_char < 'k')) {
                reverse_char = reverse_char - 'a';
                sum += (reverse_char * exp);
                exp = exp * 20;
            }
            else
            {
                reverse_char = reverse_char - 'A';
                sum += (reverse_char * exp);
                exp = exp * 20;
            }
        }
        else {
            printf("%c is not a number in base 20", reverse_char);
            break;
        }
        scanf(" %c", &reverse_char);
    }
    if (reverse_char == '\n')
        printf("%d", sum);

}
```

Comment: `(reverse_char < '10')` There is no char `10`.

Comment: Use `reverse_char <= '9'` instead.

Answer (score 2):

At least these problems:

**`" %c"` consumes leading white-space like `'\n'`**

With `scanf(" %c", &reverse_char); while (reverse_char != '\n')` , `reverse_char != '\n'` is always true.  This certainly contributes to "does not seem to work." as loop does not end.

`scanf("%c", &reverse_char);` (no space before `%c`) in two lines of code *may* work here.

**No character 10** [@tkausl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64821776/converting-a-base-20-number-to-decimal/64822095#comment114607504_64821776)

Test against `'9'`.

```
// if ((reverse_char >= '0') && (reverse_char < '10')) {
if ((reverse_char >= '0') && (reverse_char <= '9')) {
```

This hints that OP is not enabling all compiler warnings.  Best take-away here:

> Enable all warnings to save time.

**`int` overflow**

`exp = exp * 20;` can readily overflow `int` math even if `sum` in range.

**For those [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) [aficionados](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aficionado): Character encoding**

Below fails as the letter A-J are not all sequentially encoded.

```
//if ((reverse_char >= 'a') && (reverse_char < 'k')) {
//            reverse_char = reverse_char - 'a';
```

Recommend to use an array look-up.

Answer (score -1):

Any base (limited by the digits string) reversed number converting function

```
static const char digits[] = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
uint32_t toU32Reverse(const char *number, int base)
{
    uint32_t result = 0;
    const char *start = number;

    if(number && *number && base < sizeof(digits))
    {
        while(*(number)) number++;
        do
        {
            const char *pos;
            number--;
            if((pos = strchr(digits, toupper(*number))) && (pos - digits) < base)
            {
                result *= base;
                result += pos - digits;
            }
            else
            {
                result = 0;
                break;
            }
        }while(number > start);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: no, the previous question was about converting to uint32_t, so I only rewrote the reversing part :). It can be any type

Comment: Another silent DV-ter

Comment: It could be that this answer does nothing to address the question OP asked about why code does not work.  It appears your code is technically correct, but to what purpose did you post it?